# Is it possible to load an external hosted XAML file into a WPF project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

Is it possible to load an external hosted XAML file into a WPF project? 
I am trying to pull in a ResourceDictionary from an external XAML file.  I am doing this so I can style the application external from the application.
I am doing this because I want to see if this is possible because the application is going to be running on multiple computers and I don't want to have to reload upload or load a new XAML file everytime I need to make a simple change to a button color or text color.

Below are 2 options I have tried but I keep getting that the resource can not be an absolute URI.  Any pointers on how to make my XAML file load from an external hosted source?

**Try one**

```
 namespace FunWithXaml
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{

 public App()
    {
        EnsureApplicationResources();
        InitializeComponent();
    }


  public static void EnsureApplicationResources()
    {

        if (Current == null)
        {
            // create the Application object
           // new Application();

            // merge in your application resources
            Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
                LoadComponent(
                    new Uri("http://example.com/scripts/XAMLTest.xml", //This can be .xaml or .xml from my understanding if it does not have the x:Class declared in the file.
                        UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welp that didn't work.");
    }
  }

}
```

**Try Two.** Similar to above but I try to do it with using the WebClient and XamlReader.  Not sure if I am doing this part correctly though.

```
  var Blob = new Uri("http://example.com/scripts/XAMLTest.xml");
            var wc = new WebClient();
            var sourceStream = wc.OpenRead(Blob);
            StreamReader mysr = new StreamReader(sourceStream);
            FrameworkElement rootObject = XamlReader.Load(mysr.BaseStream) as FrameworkElement;

            Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(LoadComponent(rootObject)); //rootobject is giving me red lined error.
```

And Try Three. Similar to Try One but completely did away with the "If" and get an error stating I can't have an absolute URI.

```
public static void EnsureApplicationResources()
    {
    Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
            LoadComponent(
                new Uri("http://example.com/scripts/XAMLTest.xml", 
                    UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)) as ResourceDictionary);


    }
```

**EDIT**
Try Four based on the suggestion below by @Leon Zhou. But I am getting an exception error:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: ResourceDictionary LoadFrom operation failed with URI 'http://example.com/scripts/XAMLTest.xml'  ".

```
  public App()
    {
        AFunction();
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void AFunction()
    {
        var foo = new Uri("http://example.com/scripts/XAMLTest.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
        Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = foo });
    }
```

This what's in my XML file I am trying to pull.

```
 <ResourceDictionary>
 <Style x:Key="HeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
 </Style>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

This is my App.xaml file

```
 <Application
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="FunWithXaml.App"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--Trying to get dynamic XML/XAML resource to populate here-->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
    new ResourceDictionary { Source = uri }
);
```

Comment: When I try that I get an InValidOperationException.  Teh auddional info says "ResouceDictionary LoadFrom operation failed with URI 'http://example.com/scripts/XAMLTest.xml' ".  I edited my question with the XAML I am trying to work with.  That is all that is in it.

Comment: The above code would work if the uri is pointing to a "xaml" file instead of "xml" file. Is there any reason that your resource file needs the "xml" extension?

Comment: I am using XML because I have read and have successfully interchanged an XML file and XAML file for my use within the application just using the same XAML within the XML file.   I just remove the x:Class from the XAML so it does not reference the C# file. I am eventually going to be using a CMS to output an XML file so authors in the CMS can edit the styles and not have to directly edit the XAML themselves. That is the ultimate goal.  I will try the XAML extension.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Hi, I tried making my file a .xaml file with the same XAML styles in that file. Visual Studio is still having issues finding the path.  Also, when I put {StaticResource GlobalStyles} on my Grid element that I want to apply the styles to, since the 'XAMLTest.xaml' file is not part of the file system, it stops the project from launching.  I tried using DynamicResource instead and the project launches but no styles get pushed through.  Any pointers?

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that, since you are specifying an URI to the `Source` of `ResourceDictionary` class, the XAML file the URI points to must be a proper resource dictionary XAML. I have an example file here you can take a look, and feel free to use the url to test in code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20091215/Measurements.xaml

Comment: Leon Zhou,  Thanks for the pointers.  I got it working, loading it from an external source, my issue was the function needed to be called after the IntializeComponent();  That said, now I am having an issue with the application 'caching' the previous styles, would there be a way to clear this?  If I make a rectangle fill red instead of green, I am not seeing the changes.  Would you have any ideas for that?

Comment: In WPF, resources that are loaded later will overwrite existing resources with the same key. For example, if you have a rectangle style called *TitleRecStyle* in one of your resource dictionaries that gets dynamically loaded, as soon as this dictionary is loaded, the *TitleRecStyle* will overwrite the existing *TitleRecStyle* and the UI should refresh accordingly. This rule applies to implicit/default styles too.

Comment: Note that resources in WPF have their "scope". If you load your resource dictionaries to, let's say, a user control, then the new resources will only affect components inside this user control. There's also "precedence". If you load the dictionary to the app level, and there's a style defined in one of the child controls that has the same key. This more specific style in the control will take precedence and be applied within the scope of the control.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uri = new Uri("PathToMyXamlFile");
var stream = File.OpenRead(uri.ToString());
var resources = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(stream);
```

I would get the Xaml as a String into a memory stream. And then give it to the XamlReader.Load.

Comment: can you expand on your example a bit more?  I am a little confused on where in the code I would put this.  How would it be added to the MergeDictionaries section of the Application.xaml?

Comment: When I try to do your solution, I get an error in Visual Studio saying I can not convert from 'System.Uri' to 'System.IO.Stream', can you expand on your suggestion?